# Why do you use DelegatingFilterProxy in springSecurity and what are the benefits of this design?

Tags: spring-security

What I don't understand is why this security framework USES proxy classes to invoke filters. What are the benefits of this design?

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation of [DelegatingFilterProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) gives you quite pretty explanation:

> [...] All
>   calls to the filter proxy will then be delegated to that bean in the
>   Spring context, which is required to implement the standard Servlet
>   Filter interface.
>
> This approach is particularly useful for Filter implementation with
>   complex setup needs, allowing to apply the full Spring bean definition
>   machinery to Filter instances. Alternatively, consider standard Filter
>   setup in combination with looking up service beans from the Spring
>   root application context.
>
> NOTE: **The lifecycle methods defined by the Servlet Filter interface
>   will by default not be delegated to the target bean, relying on the
>   Spring application context to manage the lifecycle of that bean.
>   Specifying the "targetFilterLifecycle" filter init-param as "true"
>   will enforce invocation of the Filter.init and Filter.destroy
>   lifecycle methods on the target bean, letting the servlet container
>   manage the filter lifecycle.** [...]